# Programming image maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

I am looking for a javascript/jquery solution to build a map with selectable tracks. It will consist of area's map (image) with some river routes for boats that have to be selectable - route have to be made clearer on mouse hover and after user clicks on a route a popup window should emerge. Basically I am just looking for a solution for this type of 'map'. Maybe there are some jquery widgets/plugins that would ease the work ? I don't know where to start actually.. Can anybody give some pointers ?

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

[Maphighlight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) should do the trick.